# Attribute name with cont not accepted with ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, ransack, activescaffold

I want to search for values like a specialty name attribute but it has not been working. I have been getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Specialties#index
Showing C:/Users/surak/Pictures/groups/SD_Project_Website/app/views/specialties/index.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `SpecialtyName_cont' for #<Ransack::Search:0x000001cc33fd4598>
```

These are my ransackable attributes:

```
irb(main):001:0> Specialty.ransackable_attributes
=> ["id", "SpecialtyName", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

I have been getting this error, trying to find the right name for the cont prefix, and have tried specialty_specialtyname_cont and specialtyname_cont, as well as SpecialtyName_cont

This is my code:
index.html.erb:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :SpecialtyName_cont, 'Group ID' %>
 <%= f.search_field :SpecialtyName_cont %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
  # GET /specialties or /specialties.json
  def index
    @q = GroupAssignment.ransack(params[:q])
    @specialties = @q.result
  end
```

Comment: Is SpecialtyName an attribute in your `GroupAssignment` model?

Comment: Yes, it is an attribute